# Ask About Nofollow link on wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, plugins, nofollow

I have been searching many plugin and have tested too, but none of them have time date feature option for nofollow-ing the links. I mean, for example, all link will be automatically change to nofollow after 1 month. Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're saying but did you mean within the content and comments or what? Sounds like custom code to me.  I know of no plugin nor do I find anything in the plugin directory or codex.

Comment: link on article/post. said i publish a post which dofollow, but i want it will changed to nofollow after 1 month. for example, just like askmet plugin, they will automatically deleted spam comments after 1 month